# what does 'liken' mean when there's no 'to'

Tags: meaning

I was watching CNN 10 and I ran into this sentence.
It's about monkeys that are endangered.

> This Chinese national treasure is more endangered than the panda. It`s
> likened covered forest home at risk.

I know that 'liken to something' is comparison, but I can't understand that sentence. It doesn't seem like comparison. What does it mean exactly? Does 'likened covered' mean something in idiomatic way?
I don't even know where to cut the sentence by meaning. Does it mean this monkey is endangered and living in the forest? or this monkey is endangered and forest is in danger as well?

Comment: This is a transcript error.  The narrator actually says: "Its [lichen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lichen)-covered forest home: at risk."

Comment: @Juhasz oh, i see. thank you so much. I couldn't understand it at all. that makes sense now.